# Is it possible hide all TypeScript from a file to view only the JS logic?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I recently started a new job and we use React/TypeScript.    I've played with both, but never used them professionally.   Is there an extension for VsCode to hide/remove as much TS as possible from a file so I can see just the JS logic?   I'm still learning the TS syntax and sometimes it's too confusing seeing it all mixed up and I just want to see the actual JS logic only.

Comment: Sounds like you probably want to figure out how to look at the compiled code *without* Babel transpilation and *without* JSX transpilation. It sounds odd but it's probably doable.

Comment: Actually, most of what you see is just Ecmascript. Typescript mostly only adds types. If you're up to date with EcmaScript, you could maybe use only a good theme that dims the typings.